# Get NamedRange from unknown worksheet in other workbook

Tags: excel, vba, named-ranges

I am trying to extract data from a standardized excel form where all the values I want are namedRanges. The NamedRanges are worksheet specfic, e.g. c_001 referes to Sheet1!$X$38.

I have tried retrieving all Names in the workbook, e.g.

```
'Runtime error 13 - Type mismatch
Set namesInWb = Workbooks(wbName).Names
```

This does not seem to work though, possibly since all the names are worksheet specific?

I then thought I could get the namne through the Range object, e.g. I want to be able to use something like this to get the wsName:

```
tempRange.Worksheet.Name
```

I need to retrieve the Range object first though, but nothing I can think of works without knowing the worksheet name.

```
'Not working - Runtime error 438 - Object does not support this property or method
Set tempRange = Workbooks(wbName).Range("c_001")


'This works now, only failed due to another error earlier in the code that I had missed
Set tempRange = Range(currentName)
```

UPDATE: Last method works now. Only failed due to errors earlier in the code which I had missed.

Comment: Have you tried looping through all of the sheets to find the specific named range?

Comment: What are the errors from the above/

Comment: The [Names collection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff841251.aspx) returns all names in the active book.  Can you explain in what way this does not work?  Do you get an error message?  Sorry @Nathan_Sav; I tried to upvote your comment, but I then I accidentally downvoted it.  SO won't let me re-upvote.

Comment: @Nathan_Sav I have updated with the error messages I get.

Comment: From my perspective Workbooks(wbName).Names ought to work, but maybe it returns Nothing as there are no global Names? I am unsure if and how Excel differentiates been worksheet specific names and those who are not.

Comment: @RGA I thought about that, but it feels like a very clumsy solution. I guess that will be the last resort if there are no better solutions.

Answer (score 0):

In VBA you can also refer to named ranges by putting them in square brackets like this

```
Dim namedRange as Range
Set namedRange = [rangeName]
```

Or simply call its methods directly...

`[rangeName].Select`

Answer (score 0):

To select a range we should be knowing the worksheet name. `Range` is the method of worksheet, so we cannot apply the `Range` method on workbook.

If we do not know the sheet names under the workbook then you can use the index of worksheets as below

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("A1").Value
```

And you can also able to know the name of the sheet by using (If you require for multiple operation on the same workbook)

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Name
```

where  `ThisWorkbok` will be object of your workbook.